# Plugging fans inito a USB port

Tags: usb, fan

I'm sorry for such a simple question, but I'm pretty much brand new to this stuff.

I want to wire up in parrallel and plug in 3 little fans to a USB for power, however, these 3 fans are 12 volt .12 Amp fans and I was wondering if I'm going to be drawing too much power through that USB port that it might "burn out" so to say, or ruin it in any sort of way.

I know that USB only does 5 volts and I know the fans won't operate at full capacity this way but that isn't much of an issue for me, I don't really care that they aren't as fast as they should be.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you actually checked if your 12 V fans actually do anything at 5 V?  They might not.

Comment: I know of very few 12V fans that start at 5V. Most have the start-up voltage specified in the datasheet; around 6-8V. This is the minimum voltage they require to get started. However, if you give them a little push (to start them - overcoming the initial friction), most will work on 5V.

Answer (score 3):

You can draw maximum 500mA from a USB port, so 3 x 120mA should be OK. <s>BUT the rated current is for 12V, you'll have to check what it is at 5V.</s> Apparently at 5V the current should be lower as well (thanks, JGord), so this should work.

If you overload the port's power supply it should cut off the power.

Comment: A brushless motor load can pretty accurately be modeled as an inductor, resistor, and voltage supply(back-emf) in series. I imagine the current will still drop

Comment: @JGord, unless you stall it?

Comment: @Kortuk Right, any large torque (approaching stall torque) will bring the current up... I should've mentioned that holds at the motors no load speed.

Answer (score 3):

If you want more than 100mA from a USB port, you're supposed to negotiate with the host for it. (There might be other devices which are using all of the power.) Negotiation is going to require some IC's that speak the USB protocol.

So to be totally compliant, reducing the voltage on the fans to 5V needs to drop their current draw to 33mA. (and then they need to not spike.)

If you're not concerned about compliance, then just give it a go. As was mentioned, the power should be cut off safely if you try to draw too much.

Comment: +1 According to the USB specs a _device_ is allowed to draw no more that 100mA (known as 1 unit).  A _hub_ can negotiate up to 500mA (5 units) to power 4 devices slaved off it at no more that 100mA each, plus its own internal workings at 100mA max.

Comment: @Matt: A device can draw 100 mA without asking, and 500 mA if it negotiates first.

Comment: @endolith A device can draw up to 500mA if it lies and negotiates for more as if it were a hub.  The 500mA is intended for hub use.

Comment: @Matt I think you've misread something.  You can't plug two high-power 500 mA devices into a bus-powered hub, but you can have a high-power 500 mA device plugged directly into the port, or a 500 mA hub with 4 low-power 100 mA devices on it.

Comment: Yes, I know you _can_ have a 500mA device, once negotiated, but the _original intent_ was that the 500mA was to be for bus powered hubs, with a maximum of 4 ports.  In that situation a device _cannot_ draw more that 100mA through a port no matter what negotiation it tries - even if it is the only device on the hub.  Because of this the _only_ devices that should even consider negotiating for more power are the hubs themselves.  Anything else risks breaking the power regulations of the USB bus.